# Why a JSON path expression "*" does not yield any results (Json.NET)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Json.NET. For the following JSON:

```
var token = JToken.Parse("[\"v\"]");
```

I run two expressions:

```
var notFound = token.SelectTokens("*");
var found = token.SelectTokens("[*]");
```

For some reason the first one does not find any token, but the second one does. I've checked the behavior using [this](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com) online tool and it also proves that `"*"` should behave the same way as `"[*]"` in this case.

Json.NET is a the most popular and the most widely used framework in .NET. Thus I guess there ***is*** some reason for such a behavior... what?

Answer (score 0):

Try `/*` ?

If JSONPath is supposed to model XPath, then you'd need to specify something relative to a root -- I'd interpret the code above as 'an element of any type under the root object -- that is, it would find the strings 'under' the array.

Comment: The root in JSON path is `$`. Thus I would expect `$.*` to match all children under the root. But it does not. Neither does `$*`. However, `$[*]` works again... :/

Answer (score 0):

It is not regular expression, but Json path.
So try that from [docs](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)

```
$..*
```

It finds even more tokens - 2 instead of one(array and its element)

Comment: `$..*` returns *all members of JSON structure*.